# kernel.log contains thousands of messages about ip_len checksum. What gives?

Tags: macos, 64-bit, network

My Mac Pro Cyrus (running 10.6.8 in 64 bit mode) keeps writing the same message (for different lengths) to the kernel.log file every second:

```
 cyrus kernel[0]: in_delayed_cksum_offset: ip_len 36608 (143) doesn't match actual length 157
```

I think this has happened before I updated to 10.6.8. Just about an hour ago Cyrus had a kernel panic and needed to restart. I don't know if it is related.

I notice that Cyrus' little brother Xerxes (an iMac running 10.6.8 in 32 bit mode) doesn't have these problems.

What can it be?